# How to use constructors correctly when writing structures and what are the alternatives to Null?

Tags: haskell, tree

I'm trying to write a red-black tree in haskell. In the properties of the red-black tree there is a note that all leaves that do not contain data are black.

I want to write something like this:

```
data EmptyNode = EmptyNode{
data = ???,
color = ???,  <-- it should black (assume that it is False)
left = ???, 
right = ???
}
data NodeBR a = NodeBR {
  data :: a,
  color :: Bool,
  left :: NodeBR,
  right :: NodeBR
} 

data TreeBR a = EmptyNode | NodeBR a (TreeBR a) (TreeBR a)
```

I don't understand 2 things, what type is suitable for me to replace Null in the usual languages (undefined as I understand you can not use here) and work with constructors, how can I specify color in EmptyNode defaults to False?

Comment: You won't be using null.  You'll be using the EmptyNode you've defined instead.

Comment: While you can use `Bool` for the color as there are two options, your code may read better if you define a `Color` type with constructors `Red` and `Black`.

Comment: Your code looks very OOP-inspired. You don't need types named `EmptyNode` or `NodeBR`; those are *data constructors* defined by your `TreeBR` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to define the red-black tree (RBT for short) in a more "Haskell" way. So there are two possible ways to construct an RBT:

1. `Leaf` (`EmptyNode` in your code)
2. `Node a c l r` (`NodeBR` in your code), where `a` is the data, `c` is the color, `l` and `r` are also RBT.

```hs
data RBT a = Leaf | Node a Bool (RBT a) (RBT a)
```

In the line above, we have defined datatype `RBT a` with two constructors:

1. `Leaf :: RBT a`
2. `Node :: a -> Bool -> RBT a -> RBT a -> RBT a`

which means:

1. `Leaf` is of type `RBT a`
2. `Node` is a function, taking `a`, `Bool`(color), `RBT a` (left tree), `RBT a` (right tree), which returns an `RBT a`.

Therefore, we don't need to specify NULL in this case for `Leaf`, as there is no need for saying so at all (i.e., with Leaf, we want to say there is no data, no left/right subtree).

To treat `Leaf` as black, we could ## Heading ##define a function on `RBT a` using pattern matching:

```hs
color :: RBT a -> Bool
color Leaf = False
color (Node _ c _ _) = c
```

The [record syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/More_on_datatypes) which you have mentioned in your code is just syntactic sugar for generating such `color` function. But in this case, using record syntax cannot generate the correct code for the Leaf case, as they are not identical in the declaration.

Thus, when you have to check if an `RBT a` is `Leaf` or not, you can just use pattern matching instead of "if-with-null" in other languages.

---

Update:

As mentioned by amalloy in the comments, we could define the color as a separate datatype for better readability:

```hs
data Color = Red | Black

data RBT a = Leaf | Node a Color (RBT a) (RBT a)

color :: RBT a -> Color
color Leaf = Black
color (Node _ c _ _) = c
```

Note that `Bool` and `Color` are *isomorphic*.

Comment: Using `Bool` looks tacky compared to a custom `data Color = Red | Black`